# Why is /var/run/docker.sock not accessible in a container

Tags: docker

As `pi` user on a Raspberry Pi OS 64 I can use `/var/run/docker.sock`, but it's not accessible in a container despite being mounted.

On the host I can query `/var/run/docker.sock` just fine:

```
$ whoami
pi

$ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock 
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Dec 22 09:06 /var/run/docker.sock

$ curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/containers/json 
[]
```

I start a docker container which should have access to `/var/run/docker.sock`:

```
$ docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ubuntu bash
```

But despite being "root" in the container, `/var/run/docker.sock` is not accessible:

```
root@17bc872c1f62:/# whoami
root

root@17bc872c1f62:/# ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw---- 1 nobody nogroup 0 Dec 22 08:06 /var/run/docker.sock

root@17bc872c1f62:/# apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y
[...]

root@17bc872c1f62:/# curl -v --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/containers/json
*   Trying /var/run/docker.sock:0...
* Immediate connect fail for /var/run/docker.sock: Permission denied
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

The docker container seems to function as user `pi`:

```
$ docker run -it -v /home/pi:/home/pi ubuntu bash -c "touch /home/pi/xxx"
$ ls -l /home/pi/xxx
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 0 Dec 23 14:48 /home/pi/xxx
```

The user `pi` has been added to the `docker` group already:

```
$ id
uid=1000(pi) gid=992(docker) groups=992(docker),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),60(games),100(users),102(input),105(render),106(netdev),993(gpio),994(i2c),995(spi),1000(pi)
```

Comment: That may be user namespaces (or rootless). Please provide details about the docker engine on the host. `docker info` and `docker context inspect` may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but it could be for those who end up here, some workarounds below.

Specifying `-H unix:///var/run/docker.sock`, in addition to `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` did the trick:

```
$ docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ubuntu bash
```

The documentation for `-H` is very difficult to read for me, maybe somebody can clarify what it really does in simple terms.

The initial docker installation has been done with the installation script provided on the Docker website. But now that I reinstalled Docker by adding the apt repository and through `apt-get`, it works fine. This is how it looks now:

```
root@700852c6f51e:/# ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw---- 1 root 992 0 Dec 24 22:29 /var/run/docker.sock
```